# How to structure CMake projects

Tags: cmake

I started using CMake but am not sure how to use it in the following setup.

I have some library-cmake-projects (source code), which might depend on each other.

```
Libs
-A
-B
-C
```

(Lets say `A` depends on `C` and `B` depends on `C`)

How to make cmake be aware of the needed modules in the other directories?

Comment: This is one of the "classic" projects ... and there is **no universal approach** for it. You state several questions like "whether this approach is the correct one?", but what about just trying these approaches? In short: All approaches you note are viable ones. Just try to follow them. Would you face with a **specific** problem, you may ask about this problem (but do not forget to search before the asking). In the current form the question is **too broad**.

Comment: "How to make cmake be aware of the needed modules in the other directories?" - Without the **code** that question is still **vague**. Once more time: Try to write the code. As you know that `add_subdirectory` can be used for include other projects, then try to use it. While writting the code you could face with a **real problem**. While trying to solve the problem, you may find several solutions. Try to apply them. You may find that these approaches unacceptable for some reasons. That would be time to ask the question, with a **specific problem** and with a **specific requirements**.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to add_subdirectory, you should structure it like your source code is structured.

So, Let's say your folder structure looks like this:

```
/
-- App
-- libs
  -- A
  -- B
  -- C
```

Then you would put CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
/
-- CMakeLists.txt
-- App
  -- CMakeLists.txt
-- libs
  -- CMakeLists.txt
  -- A
    -- CMakeLsts.txt
  -- B
    -- CMakeLists.txt
  -- C
    -- CMakeLists.txt
```

/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(App)
add_subdirectory(libs)
```

/App/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(App ...)
target_link_libraries(App A B)
```

/libs/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(A)
add_subdirectory(B)
add_subdirectory(C)
```

/libs/A/CMakeListst.txt

```
add_library(A ...)
target_link_libraries(A C)
```

/libs/B/CMakeListst.txt

```
add_library(B ...)
target_link_libraries(B C)
```

/libs/C/CMakeListst.txt

```
add_library(C ...)
```

It's not good to think about add_subdirectory as having anything to with dependency management, it is about how your source and build files are organized. It also has scoping, but most of the time you don't need to worry about it. You don't necessarily need the /libs/CMakelists.txt if you directly put all three add_subdirectory calls in the top-level CMakeLists.txt but it can help with organizing.

I would refrain from using add_subdirectory to include a neighboring folder, for example. Assume the target is there and include from somewhere higher up.

Note that this is what I would recommend in general because it seems to be what the designers had in mind, but if you need something else for some reason, or have different opinion about what is correct design, then feel free to structure it differently.

Comment: Okay this is the "include it at the top-level" approach. Do you have any advice what to do, when libs has grown for some years, I start a new project that use lib `A` and I have now to follow the dependency tree of `A` to add all the needed subdirectories to my top level?

Comment: You say to refrain from using `add_subdirectory`to include neighboring folder. But is there another tool in cmake to include neigbouring folder that leads to compilation?

Comment: @generic_opto_guy Oh, you can totally use add_subdirectory to include a neighboring folder. You can give any relative or absolute path. I have a project where I do exactly that, and where it's the right thing. That being said, no if you have subdirectories of A then use add_subdirectory in A's CMakeLists.txt. Just follow the folder structure and you won't include anything twice is what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

> Is `add_subdirectory` the correct way to do this?

No, `add_subdirectory()` is used to traverse to other CMakeLists.txt files within your CMake project. It doesn't specify dependencies. In modern CMake, you really only need [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) to specify dependencies, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531208/3987854).

> How to add `C` to `A` to make this build in one call possible?
>
> I do not want to add `C` directly to `App`.

You can make `A` depend on `C` by linking the previously-defined target `C` to `A`

```
add_library(C SHARED ... )

...

add_library(A SHARED ... )

target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC C)
```

Note, the use of `PUBLIC` here ensures `C` is added to the link interface of `A`, so it will be *propagated* to consuming targets. Now, when you link `A` to `App`, you will get `C` along with it, and there is no need to specify `C` explicitly.

```
# Link A (and C) to App.
target_link_libraries(App PRIVATE A)
```

> How to handle the case that `App` also depends on `B`? With `add_subdirectory` and no caution this would try to define `C` twice. Are include guards the correct solution?

In my experience, this hasn't been an issue, and the linker was able to figure out the duplicated linked `C` library. If it does become an issue, you can simply make the scope of the `B` dependency `PRIVATE`. This way, `C` will not be propagated to `App` through `B`:

```
target_link_libraries(B PRIVATE C)

...

target_link_libraries(App PRIVATE B A)
```

I encourage you to read through the linked `target_link_libraries()` documentation, which has many examples for recommended CMake usage with these types of dependencies.

Comment: This answer made me realize, that my real confusion is about, how to make the modules be known by cmake with the least effort?