# CMake file tree

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I'm new to CMake and I'm trying to specify the following file tree:

```
|-- CMakeLists.txt
\-- src
    |-- main.cpp
    \-- graphics
        |-- context.h
        \-- private
            \-- context.c
```

And I'm really confused about all these `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY()`, `ADD_LIBRARIES()`, `TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES()`, `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES()`, etc.

How would you describe that file tree to CMake?

Right now my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.7 FATAL_ERROR)

SET(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

SET(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

PROJECT(Project VERSION 1.0.0)

# File tree stuff <<<

# GLFW
SET(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
SET(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
SET(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(dependencies/glfw)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw)

# Vulkan
FIND_PACKAGE(Vulkan REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR)
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Vulkan_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not clear in the code you provide? Do you know what `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY` does? Do you know what `ADD_LIBRARY` does (it is absent in your code)? If you have no ideas what these commands do, then it is better to read some tutorial about CMake. Stack Overflow is not a replacement for tutorials or other sources of basic information.

Comment: @Tsyvarev no, I don't have any idea about any of those, and tutorials out there are kinda crap. I've tried a bunch of combinations with those function as if i knew how they work, but nothing... so fustrating

Comment: this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302105/how-to-structure-cmake-projects